# Cordova 2.2.0 on android whitelist problems

Tags: cordova, whitelist

I'm using the cordova FileTranfer download function to download an image to my android device.
I'm using a wifi connection to download the file from my local server

I've whitelisted all domains like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<cordova>
    <access origin="*"/>
    <log level="DEBUG"/>
</cordova>
```

In LogCat i can see the following

```
01-04 16:48:09.190: D/FileTransfer(2448): download 'http://192.168.0.105/more.web/images//bf1c5a8d-0530-4c44-9e4b-0e0b29b36d10/bf1c5a8d-0530-4c44-9e4b-0e0b29b36d10DISTELDEMOAPP.jpg' to file://file:///mnt/sdcard/bf1c5a8d-0530-4c44-9e4b-0e0b29b36d10DISTELDEMOAPP.jpg
```

and after that

```
01-04 16:48:09.190: W/FileTransfer(2448): Source URL is not in white list: 'http://192.168.0.105/more.web/images//bf1c5a8d-0530-4c44-9e4b-0e0b29b36d10/bf1c5a8d-0530-4c44-9e4b-0e0b29b36d10DISTELDEMOAPP.jpg'
```

Anyways, the file isn't downloaded due to this warning (=error?)